# Resolve merge conflicts on pull using my changes

Tags: git

I want to pull a project and resolve merge conflicts using my changes.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use the *recursive* merge strategy with the *ours* option:

```
git merge -s recursive -X ours branch_to_merge
```

or

```
git pull -s recursive -X ours
```

For any conflicts, it will use the hunk that comes from your branch. See the [git merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) man page for more details.

Comment: Do you mean `-srecursive -Xours`?  The `ours` strategy will apply the *ours* side regardless of conflicts, whereas the `ours` option to the `recursive` strategy will only take the *ours* side in the case of conflicts.

Comment: @Mass, make sure you review the merge after you use `ours`. it could easily introduce bugs.

Comment: For those here looking for the same but to always accept their changes, the keyword is in fact, "theirs": git pull -s recursive -X theirs origin master

Comment: Is `-s recursive` needed? Will the new default merge strategy, [`ort`](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies#Documentation/merge-strategies.txt-ort), be fine?